# When you drag and drop the gui freezes

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop PopupBox in MaterialDesign. When drag and drop is done, the gui freezes and the data that is constantly renewed is not refreshed. How can I solve this Problem? Is it wrong to run in a separate thread? Is there just an overlooked point? Or is it all wrong?

my MouseUp Code

```
private void PortableButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
            PortableButton.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            e.MouseDevice.Capture(null);
        }));
        });
    }
```

MouseMove Code

```
private  void PortableButton_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
           
        var ActuelHeight = MainBorder.ActualHeight;
        var ActuelWidth = MainBorder.ActualWidth;
        PortableButton.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            int _tempX = Convert.ToInt32(e.GetPosition(this).X);
            int _tempY = Convert.ToInt32(e.GetPosition(this).Y);

            if (_tempX < ActuelWidth && _tempX > 0 && _tempY < ActuelHeight && _tempY > 0)
            {

                if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                
                    e.MouseDevice.Capture(PortableButton);
                    System.Windows.Thickness _margin = new System.Windows.Thickness();


                    _margin = MainGrid.Margin;
                
                    if (m_MouseX < _tempX)
                    {
                    
                        _margin.Left += (_tempX - m_MouseX);
                   
                        _margin.Right -= (_tempX - m_MouseX);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _margin.Left -= (m_MouseX - _tempX);
                        _margin.Right -= (_tempX - m_MouseX);
                    }
                    if (m_MouseY < _tempY)
                    {
                        _margin.Top += (_tempY - m_MouseY);
                        _margin.Bottom -= (_tempY - m_MouseY);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _margin.Top -= (m_MouseY - _tempY);
                        _margin.Bottom -= (_tempY - m_MouseY);
                    }
                    MainGrid.Margin = _margin;
                    m_MouseX = _tempX;
                    m_MouseY = _tempY;
                }
            }
                }));
        });

    }
```

MouseLefButtonUp Code

```
double m_MouseX;
    double m_MouseY;
    private void PortableButton_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            m_MouseX = e.GetPosition(this).X;
            m_MouseY = e.GetPosition(this).Y;
        }));
        });
    }
```

Xaml Code

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Margin="96,308,156,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" >
                    <materialDesign:PopupBox MouseUp="PortableButton_MouseUp" MouseLeftButtonUp="PortableButton_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="PortableButton_MouseMove" Name="PortableButton" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMultiFloatingActionPopupBox}" 
                                         PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignCentres" ToolTipService.Placement="Right"
                                             materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth3"
                                         ToolTip="Menü">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button Name="SystemButton" ToolTip="System" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="SystemButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <Image  Source="/Images/Icons/systemIcon.png" Width="45" ></Image>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Name="TestButton" ToolTip="Test" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown ="TestButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <Image Source="/Images/Icons/testIcon.png" Width="30"></Image>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Name="PosButton" ToolTip="Pos" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown ="PosClick">
                                <Image Source="/Images/Icons/positionIcon.png" Width="30"></Image>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </materialDesign:PopupBox>
                </Grid>
```

I add xaml code. There is constantly refreshing data on the screen. I get these with a special protocol with serialPort. Since it will be a very long code, it can be tried with the for loop that counts in the timer.

Comment: Can you add your XAML and anything else related, so I can reproduce your issue please?

Comment: I add xaml code. There is constantly refreshing data on the screen. I get these with a special protocol with serialPort. Since it will be a very long code, it can be tried with the for loop that counts in the timer.